# Action bar not show on Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar

My manifest.xml part as below:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="14" />
<activity android:name="MyActivity" android:screenOrientation="sensor" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" ></activity>
```

And in MyActivity code as below:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {    
    menu.clear();

MenuInflater i = getMenuInflater();
i.inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu);

return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);

}
```

my_menu.xml as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/test" android:icon="@drawable/test" android:title="test" android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"></item>
</menu>
```

I want to let show old menu bar while sdk before 11.
And show action bar while after sdk 11.
Now I can show menu bar before sdk 11, but not show soft menu button or action bar after sdk 11.
How can I modify it?

Comment: Here is good article http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

to

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar"
```

Also you have here [Google - Action Bar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html)

Answer (score 1):

From android.developer.com: (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html)

> Remaining backward-compatible
>
> If you want to provide an action bar in your application and remain
>   compatible with versions of Android older than 3.0, you need to create
>   the action bar in your activity's layout (because the ActionBar class
>   is not available on older versions).
>
> To help you, the Action Bar Compatibility sample app provides an API
>   layer and action bar layout that allows your app to use some of the
>   ActionBar APIs and also support older versions of Android by replacing
>   the traditional title bar with a custom action bar layout.

And here is the sample code, hope this helps you out!
Sample: http://developer.android.com/tools/samples/index.html

Answer (score 1):

remove this following line from activity as it hides actionbar

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```